# Multiple-Element Enum still Singleton?

Tags: java, enums, singleton

It's well known one of the best ways to implement a singleton is to use `Enum`, made popular by [Josh Bloch](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=3).

He states:

> This approach is functionally equivalent to the public field approach, except that it is more concise, provides the serialization machinery for free, and provides an ironclad guarantee against multiple instantiation, even in the face of sophisticated serialization or reflection attacks. While this approach has yet to be widely adopted, **a single-element enum type is the best way to implement a singleton.**

Does this still apply to a multi-element `Enum`? Won't each element be instantiated exactly once?

The perceived benefit would be to have several similar-but-different singleton-enum's, for example: each element injects a different configuration.

Example:

```
public enum Beatles {

    george("George"),
    john("John"),
    paul("Paul"),
    ringo("Ringo"),
    ;

    private Beatles(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Comment: he's wrong, enum is the worst way to implement a singleton.

Comment: @bayou.io care to elaborate?

Comment: see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/179386/what-are-the-downsides-of-implementing-a-singleton-with-javas-enum/179392#179392

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the single-element enum paradigm to support "similar but different" singletons by using a marker interface:

```
public interface MySingletonInterface {
    void doFoo(Bar bar);
}
```

Then your enums can implement the interface:

```
public enum FirstSingletonEnum implements MySingleTonInterface {

    ...

    @Override
    public void doFoo(Bar bar) {
        ... //do something with bar
    }
}

public enum SecondSingletonEnum implements MySingleTonInterface {

    ...

    @Override
    public void doFoo(Bar bar) {
        ... //do something slightly different with Bar
    }
}
```

I feel like this is a cleaner approach that jamming all implementations into a single enum.

As far as logic inside an enum, I would approach this very carefully. In general I think it is fine for an enum to encapsulate logic as long as that logic is tightly coupled to what each enum instance represents, and what the enum as a whole represents. If you're doing things like pulling in other services or talking to external entities like databases, then an enum is probably not the right choice.

Comment: In my case, I have a ConfigurationManager enum which traditionally wrapped the `Properties` API, making it far more usable, and handled a single `.properties` file. I'm trying to extend it to handle two or more `.properties` files now, which handle configurations for different components. Basically the logic is exactly the same, the only difference would be the path to the properties file.

Comment: Why not have the ConfigurationManager handle an array of files instead of just one? Then you can deal with an arbitrary number of property files. I don't know if dealing with property files really fits in an enum. Using an enum just to implement singletons just seems strange to me. Do you really face the threat of people writing sophisticated code just to create multiple instances of your singleton class? If you use a DI framework, there are ways to ensure that you're getting the same instance of a class each time (effectively a "singleton"), and that only one instance is ever created.

Comment: In my case it must be thread safe, and I have unknown developers using the system. A singleton config manager seemed to be the best way to guarantee they use it properly. Basically the only way to access it would be, for example: `ConfigManager.PersistenceConfig.getInt("app.key.value", defaultValue);`

Comment: If these unknown developers end up violating your singleton guarantee, do they end up compromising the entire system, or do they just shoot themselves in the foot? If it is the latter, then I wouldn't even bother with it. I can't think of a situation where they would *accidentally* create multiple instances if you took the regular approach. They would have to know exactly what they were doing, and if doing so is only going to hose up their stuff, then it's really only their fault.

Answer (score 1):

```
enum A {INSTANCE};
```

internally is equivalent to

```
class A {
    public static final A INSTANCE = new A();
}
```

so we can call it Singleton. But If it has more fields it cannot be called  Singleton, because Singleton pattern requires exactly one field. I think this is what Josua Bloch means

Comment: Isn't it more that a singleton guarantees that there is every only one instance of it? Having multiple fields in an enum may not necessarily violate the singleton guarantee. The OP is dealing with varying implementations so he is wondering about  `enum Impls { IMPL_A, IMPL_B; }` etc. which would be similar to one class exposing multiple singleton-implementations: `class Impls { public static final IMPL_A = ImplA.getInstance(); IMPL_B = ImplB.getInstance(); }`. Here `Impls` itself may not necessarily have to be a singleton, but `IMPL_A` and `IMPL_B` are.